# convert xml to Json in java

Tags: java, xml, mongodb, jsonml

I wan't to know how to convert an xml file to a json in java without knowing the file contents( so i could store the json in mongodb),I saw that it was possible  with JsonML,although I have read several tutorials but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: Keep in mind that XML has far more features than JSON, so when you have more complex XML documents, converting them into JSON might not be trivial. Especially when you expect it to be possible to convert them back to XML and get anything resembling the original XML file.

Answer (score 0):

One idea could be to use an XSL Stylesheet transformation for your specific XML Document Type Definition (DTD) or XML Schema (XSD), but since JSON is schema-agnostic, you could even make a generic XSL transformation to convert any XML to JSON (practically a Javascript serialized array) style

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read from an XML you should use an xmlParser,
 here a tutorial whith some examples: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_xml/java_dom_parse_document.htm

Then if you want to write it to disk or send it to a DDBB, I suggest to use Gson (is the easiest way): [read and write data with GSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19459082/read-and-write-data-with-gson)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, 
I have already developed a parser , which recovers the contained and puts it into objects and I miss just the part of converting them into json, I thought there is another way to do without  using the parser.